# cstheory.org domain redirection

Tags: feature-request, domain

I [noticed](http://whois.domaintools.com/cstheory.org) that SE has registered the **cstheory.org** domain.

Is it possible to put it to use and redirect http://cstheory.org to the [site](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com) (and http://blog.cstheory.org to the [blog](http://blog.cstheory.stackexchange.com))?

Comment: that would be awesome

Comment: I still think they should buy cstheory.se

Comment: I know someone in Sweden.

Comment: @DaveClarke if you're referring to Sweden's infamous rules about the .se domain they've significantly simplified the rules for using the domain. If SE wanted they could probably get a .se domain easy